# Select and trigger click event of a radio button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Upon document load, am trying to trigger the click event of the first radio button.... but the click event is `not triggered`.Also, tried 'change' instead of click ...but its the same result.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$("#checkbox_div input:radio").click(function() {

    $("input:radio:first").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");

    //});



    $("#checkbox_div input:radio").click(function() {

      alert("clicked");

    });

});
```

Please follow the below link to the question

Example:
http://jsbin.com/ezesaw/1/edit

Please help me out in getting this right.
Thanks!

Comment: first write click event function then call it with trigger

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You are triggering the event **before the event is even bound.**

Just move the `triggering` of the event to after attaching the event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checkbox_div input:radio").click(function() {

    alert("clicked");

   });

  $("input:radio:first").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");

});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ezesaw/16/edit)**

Answer (score 17):

Switch the order of the code: You're calling the click event before it is attached.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#checkbox_div input:radio").click(function() {

           alert("clicked");

      });

      $("input:radio:first").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");

});
```

Answer (score 5):

My solution is a bit different:

```
$( 'input[name="your_radio_input_name"]:radio:first' ).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i had to load images on radio button click, 
I just uses the regular `onclick` event and it worked for me.

```
 <input type="radio" name="colors" value="{{color.id}}" id="{{color.id}}-option" class="color_radion"  onclick="return get_images(this, {{color.id}})">

<script>
  function get_images(obj, color){
    console.log($("input[type='radio'][name='colors']:checked").val());

  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#radio1").attr('checked', true).trigger('click');
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.