# jQuery requires 2 clicks on default-checked radio button to trigger event

Tags: html, jquery

I have a sequence of radio buttons on a web page. On page-load, the first radio button in the sequence is selected by default.

In addition, there is a `<div>` associated with each radio button. (The corresponding `<div>`'s `class` is the same as the corresponding radio button's `value`.)

Even though the first radio button is `checked` by default, the jQuery ([source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-show-and-hide-div-elements-using-radio-buttons/)) does not trigger until the already-`checked` radio button is manually clicked after page-load. I learned that I can solve this by manually triggering the click myself on page-load via jQuery.

I tried doing so with `$("input:radio:first").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17980406/)), which I thought would click the first radio button in the sequence as desired, but to no success. (By the way, is this code clicking the first radio button on the page, or is it clicking the first `checked` radio button on the page? I'd prefer the code to `trigger("click")` the first `checked` radio button on the page.)

I also already hide all `<div>`s in the CSS, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31707820/3511695).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
    $(".radio_div").not(targetBox).hide();
    $(targetBox).show();
  });
});

$("input:radio:first").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");
```

```css
.radio_div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>
            <input type="radio" 
                   value="Bacon" checked="checked">Part 1</label>
  <label>
            <input type="radio" 
                   value="is">Part 2</label>
  <label>
            <input type="radio" 
                   value="Good">Part 3</label>
</div>
<div class="Bacon radio_div">Cured sugary meat</div>
<div class="is radio_div">be</div>
<div class="Good radio_div">bangin</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3qfsu6L/)

*How can I make jQuery click the default-`checked` radio button (so that its respective `<div>` appears) on page-load?*

In addition, in my actual environment (which uses a semi-customizable web builder, so it's difficult to reproduce all the code involved), the default-`checked` radio button must *always* be clicked twice in order to activate its corresponding `<div>` with the jQuery. However, I cannot replicate this behavior in JSFiddle. If anyone has any insight on what might be causing this (and how to troubleshoot/resolve), I'd be happy to hear. (Perhaps jQuery could simulate a second click whenever a radio button click is detected?)

[image]

EDIT: The issue with my production environment (in the gif) was that the `value` of the first radio button was changing to whatever radio button was previously selected. Super ridiculous.

Comment: `$("input:radio:first").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");` gets the first radio button on the page, checks it, then triggers the click event. If you want the first checked radio button, use `$("input:radio:checked:first").trigger("click");`

Comment: Put `$("input:radio:first").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");` inside `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: Note that radio buttons need to all have the same `name` in order to be mutually exclusive; your gif seems to show you got that, but the example lacks it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey @imtheman - Thank you both, I put `$("input:radio:checked:first").trigger("click");` inside `$(document).ready(function() {}`, and it solved the issue in my JSFiddle. Unfortunately the bug of needing to click on the first radio button twice (after clicking on a different radio button) still persists in my actual environment, so I'll have to look into that further

Answer (score -2):

Because you're using 2 click functions.

Comment: Where are the two click functions?